# How to prove $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^k a^{2^k}}{1+a^{2^k}}=\frac{a}{1-a}$ for $-1<a<1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to prove $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^k a^{2^k}}{1+a^{2^k}}=\frac{a}{1-a}$$ for $-1<a<1$?

It gives a hint: $2^{k+1}-1=1+2+\cdots+2^k$. How can we use this hint to cancel some terms?

Comment: I am pretty sure that the sum should begin from $k = 0$ in order for the identity to hold.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2447271/how-to-prove-sum-k-1-infty-frac2k-a2k1a2k-fraca1-a-for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a brutal-force computation: Expand everything and group according to the exponent of $a$.

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^k a^{2^k}}{1+a^{2^k}}
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^k \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{j-1} a^{j \cdot 2^k}
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{(j,k) \ : \ j \cdot 2^k = n} (-1)^{j-1} 2^k \right) a^{n}.
$$

Now write $n = m \cdot 2^r$, where $m$ is odd and $r \geq 0$. Then

- If $0 \leq k < r$, then $j = m \cdot 2^{r-k}$ is even and hence $(-1)^{j-1} = -1$.
- If $k = r$, then $j = m$ is odd and hence $(-1)^{j-1} = 1$.

So we have

$$ \sum_{(j,k) \ : \ j \cdot 2^k = n} (-1)^{j-1} 2^k
= 2^r - \sum_{j=0}^{r-1} 2^j
= 1 $$

and hence

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^k a^{2^k}}{1+a^{2^k}}
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^n
= \frac{a}{1-a}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $\displaystyle S=\sum_{r=0}^n\dfrac{2^ra^{2^r}}{1+a^{2^r}}$

$$\dfrac a{1-a}-S=\cdots=\dfrac{2^{n+1}a^{2^{n+1}}}{1-a^{2^{n+1}}}$$

Now $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{2^{n+1}a^{2^{n+1}}}{1-a^{2^{n+1}}}=?$

Comment: I guess you have a small sign mistake: $$ \frac{a}{1-a} - \sum_{r=0}^{n} \frac{2^r a^{2^r}}{1 + a^{2^r}} = \frac{2^{n+1} a^{2^{n+1}}}{1 - a^{2^{n+1}}}. $$ But otherwise it is a really cool solution! (+1)

Comment: @SangchulLee, Thanks a lot and there is a mistake in the question, right?  $k$ should start from $0$