# Evaluate $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac {z^{2^{n-1}}} {z^{2^n}-1}$, where $\lvert z\rvert \neq 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac {z^{2^{n-1}}} {z^{2^n}-1}$$
Answer: $z \over z-1$ when $\lvert z\rvert \lt 1$;$1 \over z-1$  when $\lvert z\rvert \gt 1$.

I can't think of a clue.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2447271/how-to-prove-sum-k-1-infty-frac2k-a2k1a2k-fraca1-a-for/2447281#2447281

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac {z^{2^{n-1}}} {z^{2^n}-1}=\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left(\frac1{z^{2^{n-1}}-1}-\frac1{z^{2^n}-1}\right),$$ this is a telescoping sum, so  $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac {z^{2^{n-1}}} {z^{2^n}-1}=\frac1{z-1}-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{z^{2^n}-1}.$$ This is
$$\frac1{z-1}-(-1)=\frac z{z-1}$$ for $|z|<1$, and $$\frac1{z-1}-0=\frac1{z-1}$$ for $|z|>1$.

Comment: Nice! how even do you come up with this, really hard for me.